# How can I modify the primary key when I deleting a specific row?

Tags: sql, database, phpmyadmin

Let say I have 7 row in my database and the primary key each row is 1,2,3,4,5,6,7. Now let say I deleted the third row, the primary key each row would be something like this 1,2,4,5,6,7 As you noticed the 3 was removed. I want them like this 1,2,3,4,5,6 the row with a primary key 4 is now become 3 and the 5 is now become 4 and so on.
And another one, let say I deleted the 5th row  again with a primary key 5 and then after that the primary key each row would be like this 1,2,3,4,6 Now I want them all like this again 1,2,3,4,5 the row with primary key 6 become now 5. I JUST WANT EVERY TIME I DELETE A ROW I all the primary keys are in order[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJ1De.jpg)

Comment: That's not a good idea  (update a big amount of your database when one record changes). Likely your goal doesn't justify to have to do this. Moreover, if this PK is referenced in other tables (foreign keys), the problem will be bigger.

Comment: There is no DBMS that I am aware of that allows you to update a PK. You could delete the record and create a new one. However, as the previous commenter states, this is an incredibly bad idea, would  destroy the integrity of your DB and would make it unusable

Answer (score 0):

You can update you primary key column based on row number after the deletion. Attaching sample code considering your table as "customer" and key column is "Cust_id".

```
update customer cust
JOIN
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        ORDER BY Cust_id
    ) row_num, Cust_id
    FROM customer
)AS rw_num 
ON cust.Cust_ID = rw_num.Cust_ID
set cust.Cust_ID=rw_num.row_num
```